# $lookup with $sort is not working

Tags: php, mongodb

I have two collections:'booking' and 'user'. I want to join data from `booking` and `user` with `usrLastname` sorted as ascending.

Here is the sample data.

```
booking:- {"_id": ObjectId("59a00979bb4d731037000029"),
   "cabinname": "xxxx",
   "user": ObjectId("57877d23049ac1b819000029"),
}

user:- { "_id": ObjectId("578610de049ac1741d000029"),
   "usrName": "xxxxx",
   "usrFirstname": "xx",
   "usrLastname": "xxxx",
}
```

But sorting is not working - it does not sort asc or desc.

Here is my code

```
$results = $collection->aggregate(array(
       array( '$match' => array('status'=>array('$in' => array('1', '4')),'is_delete' => 0,'cabinname'=>$eachcabin['name'],'checkin_from'=> array('$lte' => new  MongoDate()),'reserve_to'=>array('$gt' => new  MongoDate()))),
       array( '$lookup' => array(
         'from' => 'user',
         'localField' => 'user',
         'foreignField' => '_id',
         'as' => 'u'
       )),
       array( '$unwind' =>  '$u'),
       array( '$sort' => array(
         'u.usrLastname' => -1, 
       )),
     ));'
```

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific than "not working". Show some sample documents and what the expected result should be from these. Make sure you actually are pointing to the correct field names. That's pretty easy to check. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to understand what needs to be added to your question and why.

Comment: Let me reiterate "Complete and Verifiable". You are telling us "it does not sort correctly". You only show one of each document. At the "very least" you need to show us "two documents" with a "Verifiable" result that shows the order is not actually sorted as asked for. Otherwise you are just spinning a story, and likely have other problem code not listed in your question that is causing your real issue. That's why we want you do produce an MCVE that either tells us what to tell you to correct, or otherwise allows you to realize your own mistake.

Comment: You should verify your pipeline step by step. First check your match condition is working fine. Then check the lookup without unwind and then for other steps.

Comment: Yes. when i run code without unwind, its works!. Thanks Sachin

Answer (score -1):

This code works for me:

```
$mongo = new \MongoClient();
$db = MASTER_DB_NAME;
$table = $this->__table;
$c = $mongo->$db->selectCollection($table);
$search_array['deletedAt'] = "";
$pipeline = array(
    array(
        '$match' => $search_array
    ),
    array(
        '$lookup' => array('from' => "stm_userDetails",
            'localField' => "fkUserId",
            'foreignField' => "_id",
            'as' => "userArray",
        ),
    ),
    array(
        '$addFields' => array( 'userArray' => 
            array('$arrayElemAt' => array(array('$filter' => array('input' => '$userArray', 'as' => 'comp', 'cond' => array('$eq' => array('$$comp.fkUserId', $UserId)))),0))),
    ),
    array(
        '$unwind' => '$userArray',
    ),
    array(
        '$sort' => array( 'addedAt' => -1 ),
    ),
);
$cursor = $c->aggregate($pipeline);
return $cursor;
```

Hope this may help you. :)